# How to do a Hive touch command for all partitions

Tags: hive

In a hive table I have more than 3000 partitions , In short more than 10 years data. I want to do a Touch on all partitions. Do we have any command that will touch all partitions in a single go. For each date I am using the bellow command.

```
ALTER TABLE bnk.raw_bank_id TOUCH  PARTITION (process_date='2010-01-01');
```

Is there any way other than  doing 3000 Alter statement?

Answer (score 1):

In a previous Hive version it was possible to execute the next command and alter all of them: 
ALTER TABLE table_name TOUCH;

Check here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27820688&navigatingVersions=true#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTableTouch

However, in the last version, it seems that it is only posible to be done partition by partition: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionTouch

If you are using the last Hive version, unfortunatelly you will have to execute 3000 alter statements.